# Wrong triangle z-index in Three JS create an artifact

Tags: javascript, three.js, visual-artifacts

I'm using Three.js and I encountered a problem in some circumstances.
This is the problem: http://i60.tinypic.com/1zz6jac.png 
I've done my researches and I know this is a CanvasRenderer problem, there is no way to solve this without using WebGLRenderer?

I tried to use WebGLRenderer but now I have more problems because I create my script around CanvasRenderer:
http://i59.tinypic.com/9joktu.png 
Furthermore using WebGLRenderer the opacity doesn't work anymore on my cubes and lines, it can be seen it in the grid under the cubes in screenshots.

Comment: 1. What, exactly, is your question? 2. Show your code so we know what you are doing.

Comment: This is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z87uX/1/ clicking on the button change only the y position but create a glitch.

My first question is: how can I write a script without this graphic glitch using CanvasRenderer?

Comment: Is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/Z87uX/3/

Comment: This is not better, this is PERFECT.
Thanks. I'm new on stackoverflow, how can I reward your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. The best you can do is tessellate your geometry. For example,

```
THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 4 );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z87uX/3

three.js r.67